# indexedDB MB limit in smartphones browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, indexeddb

I want to know about "indexedDB" limits (In MB)  in Smartphones browsers, because im developing a mobile-web App that stores images to be browsed offline.

Answer (score 0):

Storage quota for IndexedDB, FileSystem API, etc can be query and set by [Quota Management API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/). As of now, none of the browser support it. So it is unlimited or arbitrary limit (250 MB) now.

Comment: indexedDB is not supported by any browser!!!! are u sure, cuz i can see it in chrome developer tool

Comment: I believe @KyawTun means that the Quota Management API is not supported, not IndexedDB